# Can you automatically sort video clips in Windows Live Movie Maker?

Tags: windows-live-movie-maker

When importing multiple video clips into Windows Live Movie Maker; how are they sorted?

I would like them ordered by file name. They are numbered file names and I would like them to play in numerical order.

Is there a way to sort them by file name without grabbing each individual clip and dragging it to the desired position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way. But you can select the videos in order to add them. Let us say you want to add some videos after/before one already imported, then select that video. then click on add videos (Make sure videos are sorted in the way you want in the open window).